# Using Windows Service to Create,Update,Delete CSV File using C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am creating a windows service to save current username and logon time in a CSV file. But when I install the service, the file is just created, not details are written to it, and  that file is set to read-only mode. what is the problem in my code?

My code:

```vb
   Imports System.IO
   Imports System.Text
   Imports System.DirectoryServices
   Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
   Imports System.Diagnostics
   Public Class LoginService1

      Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim win As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity
        win = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
        Dim Logon_UserName = win.Name.Substring(win.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1)
        Dim pc As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, My.Computer.Name)
        Dim uc As UserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, Logon_UserName)
        Dim str As String = ""
        Try
           Dim sr As New StreamReader("c:\logondetails.csv")
           str = sr.ReadToEnd()
           sr.Close()
           sr.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Try
           Dim sw As New StreamWriter("c:\logondetails.csv")
           Str += Logon_UserName & "," & uc.LastLogon.Value.ToString
           sw.WriteLine(str)
           sw.Close()
           sw.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
      ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.'
   End Sub

  End Class
```

Comment: Try not ignoring the exception, this will probably answer your question.

Comment: thanks for reply. then how to write coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to fix what you are doing.

For 1, you dont need to read in the entire file to append to the end of it.  For example

```
using(var stream = File.AppendText(fileName))
            {
            stream.Write(string);
            stream.Close();
            }
```

But you are going to have issues with concurrent access to the file.  You'd be better off using a logging framework, such as log4net or microsoft logging block, and then just

```
Logger.Info(yourstring);
```

and be done with it. The framework will handle the file access issues.